# appending to the strings within a list of strings in python

Tags: python

so i saw this as an answer to a question from a year ago about adding/extending a string, etc.

```
s  = 'foo'
s += 'bar'
s += 'baz'

l = []
l.append('foo')
l.append('bar')
l.append('baz')
```

my question is how would one combine these two features?  l would return:

```
['foo','bar','baz']
```

but what if i wanted to add a letter to the end of each string in the list and then have it return:

```
['food','bars','bazy']
```

is this a thing or is it more wishful thinking?

Comment: If you want to add a different character to the end of the elements of the array, then you will have to iterate over each of them, and modify them in-place.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I'm not sure I understand.  Are you looking for something like this:

```
first_list = ['foo','bar','baz']
second_list = [x+y for x,y in zip(first_list,'dsy')]
```

Answer (score 1):

you can use `zip()` along with `join()` and `map()`.

```
In [72]: lis=['foo','bar','baz']

In [73]: map("".join,zip(lis,'dsy')) 
Out[73]: ['food', 'bars', 'bazy']
```